# Looking for query using oracle or ways to implement the below requirement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Looking for solution using oracle or ways to implement the below requirement

I have two tables TABLE A and TABLE B Where the primary key in the TABLE A is 
the foreign key in TABLE B

The goal is to write the query to select the rows from the table A and for each row from TABLE A 
select the rows from the child table B where the primary key of the TABLE A matches foreign key 
of TABLE B

TABLE A

```
col1.PK     col2        col3        col4         col5       col6
AXXXXX      AXXXX       QQQQ        XXXX         XXXXa      xxxxa
BXXXXX      BXXXX       QQQX        XXXX         XXXXB      vvvvb
CXXXXX      CXXXX       QQQC        XXXX         XXXXD      xxxxd
```

TABLE B

```
colb.PK     col1.fk     col3        col4         col5       col6
AXXXXX      AXXXX       QQQQ        XXXX         XXXXa      xxxxa
BXXXXX      BXXXX       QQQX        XXXX         XXXXB      vvvvb
CXXXXX      CXXXX       QQQC        XXXX         XXXXD      xxxxd
```

FINAL OUTPUT

```
colAB1      colAB2      colAB3      colAB4       colAB5     colAB6
AXXXXX      AXXXX       QQQQ        XXXX         XXXXa      xxxxa  ---- Parent RECORD FROM TABLE A
AXXXXX      AXXXX       QQQQ        XXXX         XXXXa      xxxxa  ----- child record ( matching child records)
BXXXXX      BXXXX       QQQX        XXXX         XXXXB      vvvvb  ----- child record ( matching child records)
CXXXXX      CXXXX       QQQC        XXXX         XXXXD      xxxxd  ----- child record ( matching child records)

colAB1      colAB2      colAB3      colAB4       colAB5     colAB6
BXXXXX      BXXXX       QQQX        XXXX         XXXXB      vvvvb  ---- Parent RECORD FROM TABLE A
AXXXXX      AXXXX       QQQQ        XXXX         XXXXa      xxxxa  ----- child record ( matching child records)
BXXXXX      BXXXX       QQQX        XXXX         XXXXB      vvvvb  ----- child record ( matching child records)
CXXXXX      CXXXX       QQQC        XXXX         XXXXD      xxxxd  ----- child record ( matching child records

colAB1      colAB2      colAB3      colAB4       colAB5     colAB6
CXXXXX      CXXXX       QQQC        XXXX         XXXXD      xxxxd  ---- Parent RECORD FROM TABLE A
AXXXXX      AXXXX       QQQQ        XXXX         XXXXa      xxxxa  ----- child record ( matching child records)
BXXXXX      BXXXX       QQQX        XXXX         XXXXB      vvvvb  ----- child record ( matching child records)
CXXXXX      CXXXX       QQQC        XXXX         XXXXD      xxxxd  ----- child record ( matching child records)
```

s
For each row from table A there will be three matching rows from table B

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select *
from ((select a.*, 1 as is_a
       from a
      ) union all
      (select b.*, 0 as is_a
       from b
      )
     ) ab
order by (case when is_a then col1 else col2 end), -- col2 is the foreign key reference
         is_a desc,
         col1
```